# SCOPE OF SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL, How ensure it only set on current table or Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am currently using pyobdc to connect to MS SQL Server 2016.
So the query is how do I use 'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL' with it affecting only the current process (either set it as a connection attribute or include it in the statements) that I am running.
My Concern is whether doing that will alter the commit\lock behaviour for other connections/process that may be running and using the database.
So I am looking for is the assertion that setting TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in my scripts will only affect those scripts and not any other process that is communicating with DB.

Comment: What use would this feature possibly have if it affected all processes? As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), it affects the connection that is issuing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically to answer your question it's yes, *transaction isolation level* is scoped at the connection level, as are all other `set` options you can control such as `nocount, quoted_identifier, ansi_nulls` etc.

If you are using SSMS then the default configuration settings determine what's used by a new connection, which can then be overriden by issuing further `set` commands - all affecting the specific connection *only*.